# Change content of router-outlet from inside

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I have such a html in my app.component.html:

```
<login-menu></login-menu>
<top-menu-bar></top-menu-bar>

<div class="grid-container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

As you can see it is simple. Top menu bar injects components into router-outlet. How can I make that injected component could change this router-outlet tag content? Let say I want make that injected component have something like this:

```
<a (click)="showPersonalProfile('1')" >{{person.name}}</a>
```

and on click parent component router outlet was changed. I tried to do it by EventEmitter but I failed. Do anyone have any example how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

router-outlet is a placeholder, to show any component which matches a particular route defined in the routing-module.

By changing the route, we can control which component's app-selector gets substituted in-place of router-outlet.

So, to answer the question *How can I make that injected component could change this router-outlet tag content?* , we can do so, by navigating to that particular component using router.navigate(['*path*'] inside the *showPersonalProfile()* method.

Comment: seems that I made it overcomplicated and you are right:    this.router.navigate(['main-view', 'personal-profile']); is enough. But passing parameters to @Input does`t work :(

Comment: If the two components don't have a parent-child relationship, then using subjects would be good idea, in-order to pass parameters between two components. This would be a good reference - https://alligator.io/rxjs/subjects/

Answer (score 0):

In the function call the router navigate and set the primary path to the url you want as below

```
router.navigate([{outlets: {primary: 'path'}}]);
```